# Support for double type in texture memory in CUDA

Tags: cuda

Can 2D textures be declared for double type variables in GTX 280 having compute capability 1.3
The declaration is given only for float

Answer (score 2):

For as far as I'm aware, you can't. However, you can use the int2 type as shown in point 23 here: http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=84440

edit: Corrected grammar

Comment: Thank you.. The link which you have shared is it for Cuda compute capability 2.1 or is it just the version?

Comment: This is the fact of CUDA version 2.1. Nothing to do with compute capability. I could not find a FAQ for the recent versions of CUDA, so I just pointed to this one for the principle.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do texture interpolation with doubles, the hardware doesn't support it. What you *can* do is store the doubles as int2 and then use the tex2dfetch to collect the relevant points, convert to double, then do the actual interpolation in software.